# How to get data (key,value) from ListArray

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist, collections, hashmap

I use the code to Sort the data in the map.

```
 Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    List list = new ArrayList(map.entrySet());
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> a, Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> b) {
            return a.getValue() - b.getValue();
        }
    });
```

I just copy the data from map to List and sort it.
How can I get the data from the List? The method get() of list returns just the object, not my 2 integers

Comment: Don't use raw types. Your list should be of type List<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>. You already seem to know what a Map.Entry is, since you're sorting the list and accessing its value. So what's the problem? Have you read the javadoc of Map.Entry?

Answer (score 1):

Your `list` actually contains elements of type `Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>`, so you can retrieve the each `Entry` as shown below:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
//add the values to map here

//Always prefer to use generic types shown below (instead of raw List)
List<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());

Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> a,
                  Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> b){
                       return a.getValue() - b.getValue();
    }
  });

  //loop over the list to retrieve the list elements
  for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : list) {
        System.out.println(entry.getValue());
  }
```

Comment: My Eclipse can not convert from element type Object to Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>.

Comment: @MikhailNono that's precisely because you declared your list as List, rather than List<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>. Read all the answers and comments you got instead of ignoring them. If you didn't ignore them and still have a problem, then edit your question, post your new code, and post the exact and complete error message you get from the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You do that :

```
 List list = new ArrayList(map.entrySet());
```

You could use generics in your list and then iterate on the `Entry` of the list after your sorted it:

```
List<Entry<Integer, Integer>> list = new ArrayList(map.entrySet());
...
// your sort the list
..
// you iterate on key-value
for (Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : list){
  Integer key =  entry.getKey();
  Integer value =  entry.getValue();
}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The method values() is undefined for the type List
 Syntax error, insert ")" to complete EnhancedForStatementHeader

 at packS.SecondProject.SecondProject.main(SecondProject.java:85)

Comment: refresh the page I think. And don't forget to declare the `List` with the generic type. For the imports, specify  those in `java.util`.